# How to create a vertical pagination with a fixed view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view

I have 4 fragments and I want to create a sort of vertical viewpager but I need to keep visible a view of the previous page.

In more details:
Fragment A have a TextView (TV1) on the bottom and other views.
Fragment B have a TextView (TV2) on the bottom and other views.
Fragment C have a TextView (TV3) on the bottom and other views.
I start my Activity, Fragment A occupies the entire layout.
Click on a button -> Fragment A slides up and Fragment B appears but TV1 should still be visibile and fixed on the top of the screen.
Click on a button -> Fragment B slides up and Fragment C appears but TV2 should still be visibile and fixed on the top of the screen (TV2 should replace TV1)...
If I click on TV2 the Fragment B will reappear above the Fragment B.

[image: Example Image]

How can I obtain this behavior?

Comment: I think this might be a place where you are using `Fragment`'s but should be using `CustomView`'s inside of 1 `Fragment`. Then your desired behaviour is much easier

Comment: @Blundell Thank you for the reply. Can you give me more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to implement something similar to what you ask about. Here's how it looks:

[image]

It might a bit hacky, though that's how I archive it:

First, I needed some `TvFragment`:

```
public class TvFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tv_fragment, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvTextView);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((OnScrollChanged)getActivity()).onScroll(TvFragment.this);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    public void display(int height, String tvTitle, int backgroundColor) {
        if (getView() == null) {
            return;
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getView().getLayoutParams();
        params.height = height;
        getView().setLayoutParams(params);

        TextView textView = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tvTextView);
        textView.setText(tvTitle);
        getView().setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    }
}
```

And it's `tv_fragment.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/tvTextView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_backgroud_selector"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/tv_button_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tv_button_height" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And then we need to fill the `Activity` with our Fragment

Then, we need to have an adapter to fill it with our fragments:

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="klogi.com.verticalpagination.TvFragment"/>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="klogi.com.verticalpagination.TvFragment"/>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentC"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="klogi.com.verticalpagination.TvFragment"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I.e. we keep all three fragments in one `ScrollView`.

Small helper `interface` to communicate between fragment and activity:

```
public interface OnScrollChanged {
    void onScroll(Fragment fragment);
}
```

And last piece is `MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnScrollChanged {

    TvFragment fragmentA;
    TvFragment fragmentB;
    TvFragment fragmentC;

    int bigFragmentHeight;
    int smallFragmentHeight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        bigFragmentHeight = metrics.heightPixels - getStatusBarHeight();
        smallFragmentHeight = bigFragmentHeight - getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.tv_button_height) - 2 * getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.tv_button_margin);

        fragmentA = (TvFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentA);
        fragmentA.display(bigFragmentHeight, "TV1", Color.BLUE);

        fragmentB = (TvFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentB);
        fragmentB.display(smallFragmentHeight, "TV2", Color.RED);

        fragmentC = (TvFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentC);
        fragmentC.display(smallFragmentHeight, "TV3", Color.YELLOW);

        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        scrollView.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(Fragment fragment) {
        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        int currentScroll = scrollView.getScrollY();

        if (fragment.equals(fragmentA)) {
            if (currentScroll == 0) {
                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, smallFragmentHeight);
            } else {
                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
            }
        } else if (fragment.equals(fragmentB)) {
            if (currentScroll == smallFragmentHeight) {
                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, smallFragmentHeight + bigFragmentHeight);
            } else {
                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, smallFragmentHeight);
            }
        } else if (fragment.equals(fragmentC)) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing here - is to disabling "normal" scrolling of the `ScrollView` and depends on which fragment's button has been clicked - smooth scrolling up or down.

I used also this resources:
dimens:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="tv_button_height">48dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tv_button_margin">8dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

colors:

```
<resources>
    <color name="textview_backgroud">#AAAAAA</color>
    <color name="textview_backgroud_pressed">#777777</color>
</resources>
```

and textview_backgroud_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/textview_backgroud_pressed"/>
    <item android:color="@color/textview_backgroud"/>
</selector>
```

I've uploaded the complete project into my dropbox - [feel free to check it out](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y76bjucrce3xud0/VerticalPagination.zip?dl=0)

That's it! I hope, it helps